# Can ASP query a database located on another server?

Tags: asp-classic

I wanted to know if it's possible to have a page on another server query the database on our server, or is that a big security no no?

Comment: That's great. So it's an MSSQL server on our webserver that I'd be calling to. So essentially you're all saying that I need to create a unique database user/credentials for that use and then I should be good to go?

Comment: Yes. You have 2 authentication choices: SQL Server or Windows. Here is an [ASP-specific explanation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247931) and here is [a bit more detail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common practice.

Sometimes several applications are sharing the database(s).

Sometimes the database is on its own server so that the server can be optimized for the database, and the database can use all of the server resources instead of sharing them with the web server.

Security is handled by setting permissions in the database, regardless of whether the calling application is on the same machine. Generally, applications will operate with their own identity and credentials. They are given very limited permissions on the database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, you should just make sure that you follow proper steps to minimize any security risks. How is your page going to connect? What type of connection? Make sure the permissions to the DB are only based on what the page needss and nothing more. Make sure your page also protects against possible attacks such as SQL injection, etc.

In short, yes this is possible and perfectly normal. I do recommend you do some research on proper practices and preferred security settings.

Answer (score 0):

it can do so, without any security violations.